# Re-Save Internal rules in Pega 7

Tags: pega

Is it possible to re-save `Internal` rule in custom ruleset without `Internal` label?

For example: I've saved `pzModalTemplate` in my ruleset with name `UserProfileModalTemplate` and make some changes in it. In top of rule form it says: Section `UserProfileModalTemplate [Available, Internal]`.

Since it is `Internal` it cannot be found in Search.

So, question is - How can I change its status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like a bug to me that Pega is not allowing to change the `Rule Status` once it is set to `Internal`.

But one solution I can offer.

1 ) Create a `Utility(Activity)`.

2 ) Create a page as `Section` of `Rule-HTML-Section` class.

3 ) Copy the `pzInsKey` of the Section rule and copy into `Obj-Open-By-Handle` method. Put `Section` in `Step Page`.

4 ) Once the `Section Page` is open, Set the Property `pyMethodStatus` to `""` in `Property-Set` method.

5 ) `Save` the `Section Page`.

6 ) `Commit` the `Section Page`.

Refresh the `Section`.

Now delete the `Activity` if you don't need it

This solution solved it at my end.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: One should point out that Pega's naming convention indicates that rules starting with `pz` should **not** be touched though.